# Maintaining Directory Structure when loading local files into UIWebview on iPhone

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

I'm noticing a minor annoyance when working with local files in a UIWebview and hoping there is a simple workaround. As a simplified example lets say in my xCode project I have a folder called "WebProject" that contains an html file and a subfolder called "images" where the images reside. The html file references the images as you'd expect: src="images/MYIMAGE.jpg" for example, which works just dandy if this where are normal webpage. When you load the html file in a UIWebview, however, this image would not show up because it seems that all of the files are just thrown into one big bundle folder (so the image link is actually: src"MyIMAGE.jpg"). Is there anyway to enforce the directory structure of these files in the main bundle, so that this sort of thing does not happen? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Just create the structure you want in the filesystem (using finder or whatever) and import that whole tree into your project. Make sure you select "Create folder references for any added folders"

You'll notice these folders are blue instead of the normal yellow used for groups. This folder structure will exist in the bundle and so your relative references will work as you expect.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

See [this page](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/managing-files-and-folders-in-your-xcode-project#Add-existing-files-and-folders-to-a-project) for how to add resources, and maintain directory structure. Make sure you select the radio button that says "Create folder references for any added folders." Then when you go to write your code, folder-relative paths to the bundle will resolve just as if they are sub-directories. Because they are, even in your app's resources.

Comment: Link is dead, but answer is still accurate.

Comment: Updated dead link